# How can I define a replacement pattern in SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, ms-access, functional-programming

serious database n0ob here,

My question is as follow: I want to update a table in Access with another table using a join. However, the columns who make up the join between the two tables might not be perfectly the same. For example, one field might be `AAA-000` and its corresponding field `AAA/000`.

Now I come from Mathematica where we could simply define rules indicating that some things could be considered the same, for example the "/" and the "-" characters would be "isomorphic"...

How can I tell Access (or SQL for that matter) how to consider a set of characters as the same? (In the same way "a" and "A" would be the same because if it were case insensitive)

Thanks a lot

EDIT : And if possible, how slower would such a query would be? Is it better anyway to just clean both tables in Excel?

Comment: In general it's better to clean the data and then process it.  If it's just being cleaned for OUTPUT, the overhead may be low.  But if you need to clean it before you JOIN on it, or use it in a WHERE clause, you probably nerf any ability to use an index.  In which case, cleaning it first is Highly advisable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't do that in Access. What you need to do, is transform one source into the other while doing joins, or just normalize both tables before joining them. For example, if the source field, say `Name` had the value `aaa-000` and you wanted to transform it into `AAA/000`, you could use the following:

```
UCase(Replace([Name], "-", "/"))
```

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, thanks a lot. Only problem I can see is that the query could easily beef up by using two or three Replace commands on both sides. Well, I guess you just can't beat functional programming conciseness and elegancy.

Comment: Yes, transforming the field on both sides will probably turn your query slower, because then the optimizer would not be able to use any existing index on those fields. Can't you normalize the tables before joining them?

Comment: One of the table is a static table : no problem. The other one is a linked table, and I can't touch its index field. Yet I guess I could first import it in a static table, then clean it up, then run the update query. It makes a lot of steps tough (although I guess one could do it with VBA. Any reference?) Again, I'm a noob so the problem is probably simpler than that.

Comment: It'd be harder to do that using VBA, but if you are going to need to do these updates often, then it's probably the better way to do it. There are lots of VBA tutorials online, but I can't really recommend one in particular; I normally search for a specific thing that I want to do.